# xsl transformation: rename a tag (for access)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file that I want to import in Access.  Access is doing a fine job of it except that it doesn't like having a "." in the name. So I basically want to replace "netw.NetworkElement" in "NetworkElement"

This is an example input

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP:Header>
    <header xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
        <requestID>client1:0</requestID>
        <requestTime>Feb 1, 2017 2:46:46 PM</requestTime>
        <responseTime>Feb 1, 2017 2:46:46 PM</responseTime>
    </header>
</SOAP:Header>
<SOAP:Body>
    <findResponse xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
        <result>
            <netw.NetworkElement>
                <mgmtIpAddrType>ipv4</mgmtIpAddrType>
                <ipAddress>10.27.64.19</ipAddress>
                <baseMacAddress>C4-08-4A-07-97-C1</baseMacAddress>
                <systemAddress>10.27.64.19</systemAddress>
                <sysDescription>N/A</sysDescription>
                <outOfBandAddress>192.168.0.1</outOfBandAddress>
                <inBandSystemAddress>10.27.64.19</inBandSystemAddress>
                <inBandL3ManagementIf>0.0.0.0</inBandL3ManagementIf>
                <location>TL000075</location>
                <coordinates>10b, Shevchenko str., Tula</coordinates>
                <chassisType>sas_shelf_7210_m_24f2xfp_etr</chassisType>
                <productType>19</productType>
                <sysObjectId>.1.3.6.1.4.1.6527.6.2.1.2.2.3</sysObjectId>
                <latitudeInDegrees>0.0</latitudeInDegrees>
                <longitudeInDegrees>0.0</longitudeInDegrees>
                <neState>managed</neState>
                <locationId>0</locationId>
                <olcState>inService</olcState>
                <siteId>10.27.64.19</siteId>
                <deploymentState>0</deploymentState>
                <objectFullName>network:10.27.64.19</objectFullName>
                <name>10.27.64.19</name>
            </netw.NetworkElement>
            <netw.NetworkElement>
                <mgmtIpAddrType>ipv4</mgmtIpAddrType>
                <ipAddress>10.27.64.28</ipAddress>
                <baseMacAddress>C4-08-4A-07-1A-5D</baseMacAddress>
                <systemAddress>10.27.64.28</systemAddress>
                <sysDescription>N/A</sysDescription>
                <outOfBandAddress>192.168.2.3</outOfBandAddress>
                <inBandSystemAddress>10.27.64.28</inBandSystemAddress>
                <inBandL3ManagementIf>0.0.0.0</inBandL3ManagementIf>
                <location>TL000018</location>
                <coordinates>96, Sovetskaya av., Tula</coordinates>
                <chassisType>sas_shelf_7210_m_24f2xfp_etr</chassisType>
                <productType>19</productType>
                <sysObjectId>.1.3.6.1.4.1.6527.6.2.1.2.2.3</sysObjectId>
                <latitudeInDegrees>0.0</latitudeInDegrees>
                <longitudeInDegrees>0.0</longitudeInDegrees>
                <neState>managed</neState>
                <locationId>0</locationId>
                <olcState>inService</olcState>
                <siteId>10.27.64.28</siteId>
                <deploymentState>0</deploymentState>
                <objectFullName>network:10.27.64.28</objectFullName>
                <name>10.27.64.28</name>
            </netw.NetworkElement>
        </result>
    </findResponse>
</SOAP:Body>
```

This is the expected output:

```
<NetworkElement>
                <mgmtIpAddrType>ipv4</mgmtIpAddrType>
                <ipAddress>10.27.64.19</ipAddress>
                <baseMacAddress>C4-08-4A-07-97-C1</baseMacAddress>
                <systemAddress>10.27.64.19</systemAddress>
                <sysDescription>N/A</sysDescription>
                <outOfBandAddress>192.168.0.1</outOfBandAddress>
                <inBandSystemAddress>10.27.64.19</inBandSystemAddress>
                <inBandL3ManagementIf>0.0.0.0</inBandL3ManagementIf>
                <location>TL000075</location>
                <coordinates>10b, Shevchenko str., Tula</coordinates>
                <chassisType>sas_shelf_7210_m_24f2xfp_etr</chassisType>
                <productType>19</productType>
                <sysObjectId>.1.3.6.1.4.1.6527.6.2.1.2.2.3</sysObjectId>
                <latitudeInDegrees>0.0</latitudeInDegrees>
                <longitudeInDegrees>0.0</longitudeInDegrees>
                <neState>managed</neState>
                <locationId>0</locationId>
                <olcState>inService</olcState>
                <siteId>10.27.64.19</siteId>
                <deploymentState>0</deploymentState>
                <objectFullName>network:10.27.64.19</objectFullName>
                <name>10.27.64.19</name>
            </NetworkElement>
            <NetworkElement>
                <mgmtIpAddrType>ipv4</mgmtIpAddrType>
                <ipAddress>10.27.64.28</ipAddress>
                <baseMacAddress>C4-08-4A-07-1A-5D</baseMacAddress>
                <systemAddress>10.27.64.28</systemAddress>
                <sysDescription>N/A</sysDescription>
                <outOfBandAddress>192.168.2.3</outOfBandAddress>
                <inBandSystemAddress>10.27.64.28</inBandSystemAddress>
                <inBandL3ManagementIf>0.0.0.0</inBandL3ManagementIf>
                <location>TL000018</location>
                <coordinates>96, Sovetskaya av., Tula</coordinates>
                <chassisType>sas_shelf_7210_m_24f2xfp_etr</chassisType>
                <productType>19</productType>
                <sysObjectId>.1.3.6.1.4.1.6527.6.2.1.2.2.3</sysObjectId>
                <latitudeInDegrees>0.0</latitudeInDegrees>
                <longitudeInDegrees>0.0</longitudeInDegrees>
                <neState>managed</neState>
                <locationId>0</locationId>
                <olcState>inService</olcState>
                <siteId>10.27.64.28</siteId>
                <deploymentState>0</deploymentState>
                <objectFullName>network:10.27.64.28</objectFullName>
                <name>10.27.64.28</name>
            </NetworkElement>
```

I've read this forum, tried different xsl transformations, but I just don't understand how xsl work. So far, I've only been able to copy the input file :-(

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- Template to match 'netw.NetworkElement' and replace with 'NetworkElement' -->
<xsl:template match="netw.NetworkElement">
    <NetworkElement>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </NetworkElement>
</xsl:template>

 <!-- Template to match all nodes, copy them and then apply templates to children. -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Your example output doesn't have any of the SOAP stuff or the `<findResponse>` or `<result>`. Do you want to remove all of those?

Comment: well I'm only interested in creating one row in access for each network element => if we can remove them as well, it's even better. When I import in Access, I get a header table that I don't really want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it mostly right. You just need to take namespaces into account:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xapi="xmlapi_1.0"
                xmlns="xmlapi_1.0"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xapi">
    <!-- The namespace is declared twice here:

           - once with a prefix so that it can be referred to with XPath
             (xapi:netw.NetworkElement)

           - once without a prefix so that the <NetworkElement> element
             below is output in the correct namespace
    -->

    <!-- Template to match 'netw.NetworkElement' and replace with 'NetworkElement' -->
    <xsl:template match="xapi:netw.NetworkElement">
        <NetworkElement>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </NetworkElement>
    </xsl:template>

     <!-- Template to match all nodes, copy them and then apply templates to children. -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Explanation of how this works

#### Matching the element correctly

In your input XML, the `findResponse` element has the namespace declaration `xmlns="xmlapi_1.0"`, which means that it and all the elements within it are in the namespace `xmlapi_1.0`, unless stated otherwise.

Your XSLT has `match="netw.NetworkElement"`, but this XPath expression (`netw.NetworkElement`) has no namespace prefix, which means that it matches elements in the `null` namespace. The element you are trying to rename is *not* in the null namespace, so this first `xsl:template` doesn't catch anything.

To fix this, I did two things:

- Add the namespace declaration `xmlns:xapi="xmlapi_1.0"` to the top of the stylesheet, so that I can refer to this namespace by using the prefix `xapi`.
- Modify the `match` attribute to use this prefix: `xapi:netw.NetworkElement`.

After this modification, your XSLT would catch the `netw.NetworkElement` and rename it, but there would still be one problem...

#### Outputting `NetworkElement` in the correct namespace

The remaining problem would be that by default, `NetworkElement` would be output in the null namespace, which means that it would have a different namespace from all of the other elements:

```
<findResponse xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
    <result>
        <netw.NetworkElement xmlns="">
            <mgmtIpAddrType xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">ipv4</mgmtIpAddrType>
            <ipAddress xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">10.27.64.19</ipAddress>
            ...
        </netw.NetworkElement>
        <netw.NetworkElement xmlns="">
            ...
        </netw.NetworkElement>
    </result>
</findResponse>
```

I don't think we want this, so I remedied this by adding the namespace declaration `xmlns="xmlapi_1.0"` to the top of the stylesheet. This makes it so that, by default, any element literals like `<NetworkElement>` will be output with that namespace instead of the `null` namespace.

#### The `xmlns:xapi="xmlapi_1.0"` in the output.

As you observed in the comments, there is one bit of weirdness, which is that the `NetworkElement` has a `xmlns:xapi="xmlapi_1.0"` namespace declaration on it in the output. This shouldn't cause any problem, but it's also not doing anything useful by being there, so there is a way to omit it: by adding the attribute `exclude-result-prefixes="xapi"` to the top of the stylesheet. This will ensure that the `xapi` declaration will not be used unless it's necessary.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot!
It's working just fine. I don't understand what the magic with namespaces is, but your trick did it

Maybe you can explain: after transformation, the output, is now

    <findResponse xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
   <result>
    <NetworkElement xmlns:xapi="xmlapi_1.0">
                     ....
    </NetworkElement>

so, your trick added something about xmlapi. It's working fine: I can use my xsl and import in access with it, so I'm Ok with the solution, if you can explain me what happens for my future improvement

Comment: @L1bzh Added a detailed explanation above and made a modification to the XSLT that should get rid of that `xmlns:xapi="xmlapi_1.0"` in your output.

Comment: thanks a lot, I think I'm starting to understand too :) your modification did have the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

In **XSLT 1.0**

USE This

```
  <xsl:template match="*[local-name(.) = 'netw.NetworkElement']">
        <NetworkElement>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </NetworkElement>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is a sloppy way to get around using namespaces correctly and will result in `<NetworkElement>` having a different namespace from all its descendant elements.